# Not able to create a new folder in side etc in linux

Tags: linux

I have been trying to create a folder in /etc in ubuntu 20.10 but it is showing
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘wiki’: Permission denied
the above error message. how to resolve this

Thanks!...

Comment: You would generally not create folders in `/etc` unless you are manually installing a package outside of your package manager. If you want to create a directory anyways, use `sudo mkdir /etc/wiki` to run the command as root which has access

Answer (score 1):

You need to have root permission to create document. Your current user doesn't have root privileges. You can use  `$sudo mkdir /etc/wiki` to create folder.

Another option is to add your user to `sudo` group. For example, your user name is 'ubuntu' the you can execute the following command to add user to `sudo` group

- `$ sudo usermod -aG sudo ubuntu`

To verify user belongs to Sudo Group

- `$ groups ubuntu`

Output

- `ubuntu : ubuntu sudo`

Once you have added your user(ubuntu) to Sudo group, you don't have to use `sudo` with every command.